# UIColor variable values are null for the first instance in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, uicolor

I am trying to create a UIColor variable and shared instance method in my AppDelegate.h file, which can be used to access the value of this variable anywhere in the application. Here  below is my code for AppDelegate.h-

```
+(AppDelegate *)sharedInstance;
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIColor * darkColorC1;
```

and for AppDelegate.m-

```
+ (AppDelegate *)sharedInstance {
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
static AppDelegate *instance = nil;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    instance = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
});
return instance;
}
```

I have a class in which different colors are displayed on tableview, and when i try to select any one of the color, it gets saved into NSUserDefaults. I am trying to assign the color saved in userdefaults to this darkcolorc1 variable using below statements-

```
AppDelegate *globals = [AppDelegate sharedInstance];
globals.darkColorC1 = color1;
```

I am able to store the color1(Userdefaults) value into my AppDelegate variable darkColorC1, and when i close the app and try to run it again, i get the current color selected value in Appdelegate method -didFinishLaunchingWithOptions . But when i try to assign that color to my first view controller it shows null value. 
For eg-

```
AppDelegate *globals = [AppDelegate sharedInstance];
self.view.backgroundcolor= globals.darkColorC1;
```

it shows null value for globals.darkColorC1.

Also when i try to select any other color and store it in globals.darkColorC1 variable and try to load my first view controller the value is not null this time.
Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: AppDelegate is a custom class, or the `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`?

Comment: it is [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

Comment: Why do you have a custom init and custom shared instance for it then?

Comment: so how do i access the app delegate variable then. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: `AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; `self.view.backgroundColor = appDelegate.darkColorC1;`. But I wouldn't surcharge the `UIApplicationDelegate` with that kind of stuff, and create another singleton to do that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. it worked for me. but is it a good solution  or is there any alternate method for it as you said about the use of singleton.

Answer (score 0):

AppDelegate's object doesn't need to be created like this, you can use the object of AppDelegate like this

```
AppDelegate *appDelObj = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Also, Why are you dumping this type of variables in `AppDelegate` class, create a singleton for those type of variables which you want to access throughout the Application.

For Example

In the .h class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyDataHandler : NSObject

+ (instancetype)sharedDataHandler;

@property(nonatomic,strong) UIColor * darkColorC1;

@end
```

Now in you .m class

```
#import "MyDataHandler.h"

@implementation MyDataHandler

+ (MyDataHandler *) sharedDataHandler {
    static id _sharedHandler = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _sharedHandler = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedHandler;
}
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Now you can access this variable like this

```
[MyDataHandler sharedDataHandler].darkColorC1
```

Comment: ok. now i got it. thanks for the suggestions . But can you tell me when does this class gets called or how do i call the methods from this class?

Comment: I have mentioned it in the Answer - [MyDataHandler sharedDataHandler].darkColorC1